# How to modify list inside a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun list-parser (list count)
  ...);;this function reads items by count from list and do some process to them.

;;i.e.convert items read from code to char, or to other things and then return it. 

;;Also, the items in list should be consumed, globally. 

(defmethod foo ((obj objtype-2) data-list)
  (setf (slot-1 obj) (read-list data-list 1))
  obj)

(defmethod foo ((obj objtype-1) data-list)
  (setf (slot-1 obj) (read-list data-list 1)
        (print data-list)
        (slot-2 obj) (read-list data-list 2)
        (print data-list)
        (slot-3 obj) (foo (make-instance 'objtype-2) data-list)
        (print data-list)
        (slot-4 obj) (read-list data-list 3))
  obj)
```

How to let it work like this:(read-list just works like read-byte in some way:

1.return a value read(and parsed here)

2.change the stream position(here the list)).

```
(let ((obj)
      (data))
  (setf data '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
        obj (foo (make-instance 'objtype-1) data))
  (print data))
>>(2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
>>(4 5 6 7 8)
>>(5 6 7 8)
>>(8)
```

Or rather, how do you deal with this kind of task? Do you convert list to other type?

Comment: Okay, for now I conver list to array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are after, but here is a function which creates a 'list reader' object (just a function).  A list reader will let you read chunks of a list, treating it a bit like a stream.

```
(defun make-list-reader (l)
  ;; Make a list reader which, when called, returns three values: a
  ;; chunk of list, the length of tha chunk (which may be less than
  ;; how much was asked for) and the remaining length.  The chunk is
  ;; allowed to share with L
  (let ((lt l)
        (len (length l)))
    (lambda (&optional (n 1))
      (cond
       ((zerop len)
        (values nil 0 0))
       ((< len n)
        (values lt len 0))
       (t
        (let ((it (subseq lt 0 n)))
          (setf lt (nthcdr n lt)
                len (- len n))
          (values it n len)))))))

(defun read-from-list-reader (r &optional (n 1))
  ;; Read from a list reader (see above for values)
  (funcall r n))
```

And now:

```
(defvar *l* (make-list-reader '(1 2 3)))
*l*

> (read-from-list-reader *l* 1)
(1)
1
2

> (read-from-list-reader *l* 2)
(2 3)
2
0

> (read-from-list-reader *l* 10)
nil
0
0
```

What you can't really do is write a function (not actually a function of course since it modifies its argument) which works like this while modifying its argument list.  So you can write a function which will do this:

```
> (let ((l (list 1 2)))
    (values (read-from-list l)
            l))
(1)
(2)
```

which works by modifying the `car` and `cdr` of the first cons of `l` as you'd expect.  But this can't work when there is no more to read: `l` is a cons and `nil` isn't a cons, so you can't ever make `l` `nil` with a function.

But in any case such a function is just a mass of traps for the unwary and generally horrid: for instance your example would involve modifying a literal, which isn't legal.